# Focusing screen for Canon EOS 3/EOS 1V

Tags: canon, focusing-screen

I'm looking for an alternative to the native Canon EC series focusing screens, more specifically to the EC-A, EC-B, EC-D, EC-L. Due to some circumstances the only marketplace available to me is aliexpress.

Does anyone know any seller or brand I can find there? Or perhaps there is a DIY way to modify (basically, cut) the screens intended for Canon 5D series to fit into EOS 3/1V?

Comment: A quick Google search shows that EC focus screens are available at Canon, B&H, etc. Why are you only able to buy from Aliexpress?

Comment: @MikeSowsun Given the OP's name, perhaps a ban of exports to Russia...

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found on aliexpress focusing screen that fits, at least mechanically. Didn't test it yet in terms how it affects exposure measurements.

In case anyone else is looking for it: this is a lot I originally found:
https://aliexpress.ru/order-list/5300763561520638?spm=a2g2w.orderlist.0.0.1be74aa6bqLACL&filterName=active

This is a screen manufactured by chinese company named Bresson. Here is the google-translated description page:
https://www-bresson-com-cn.translate.goog/Product/7608322821.html?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=ru&_x_tr_pto=wapp&_x_tr_sch=http

After I purchased the screen shown in the picture, I contacted the seller and he told me that he can sell me any Bresson screen I want, which I did.

Hope that is helpful to someone.

Comment: "this is a lot I originally found" - broken URL.